# Timelion syntax doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, timelion

I'm trying to use [timelion](https://github.com/elastic/timelion).

When I tried `es(*)` function, I got no result.

I have a dataset in elasticsearch, and structure is

```
{
    "_index": "test",
    "_type": "testtype",
    "_id": "abcdefg0",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
        "name": "name",
        "gender": "Male",
        "timestamp": "2016-07-26T06:10:56Z"
        "is_foreigner": false
    }
}
```

all fields consist of `string` type except timestamp field. (timestamp field consists of date type)

Do I need additional field? or Do I need to add any `number` field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found solution.

timestamp field name is wrong.

You must use `@timestmap` as timestamp field.

Or, if you want to use custom field, Go to `timelion.json` file and change timelion configuration.

```
"es": {
    "timefield": "timestamp",
    "default_index": "sensor_log",
    "allow_url_parameter": false
 }
```

like this.

timelion.json default value is

```
"es": {
    "timefield": "@timestamp",
    "default_index": "sensor_log",
    "allow_url_parameter": false
 }
```

Self question, self answer :(

Anyway, I could help somebody through this answer. :)